# Webpart properties not shown in propertypane

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Just created a simple Visual WebPart for SharePoint. There is no code in yet. All I want is that the "Whatever"-Property is shown in the Propertypane of that webpart. But it isn't.

(Not even the category is shown)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using WebPart = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart;

namespace tqUpdateOrder.ListOrder
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class ListOrder : WebPart
    {
        // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/tqUpdateOrder/ListOrder/ListOrderUserControl.ascx";

        private string _whatever;

        [Browsable(true),FriendlyName("oink"),WebBrowsable(true),WebDisplayName("OINK OINK"),Category("HIER BIN ICH")]

        public string Whatever
        {
            get { return _whatever; }
            set { _whatever = value; }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A shot in the dark but if you added the web part to a page before you put the property in the class and then redeployed with the property you would need to delete the web part from the page and add it again.

Comment: Thanks. But did that already

Comment: I "solved" this by recreating a new SharePoint project and starting all over. Some of those "magic" SharePoint - Moments, I guess